# OOP PHP unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, php-parse-error

I am trying out OOP PHP and I seem to have run into a bit of a problem.

```
    class Connection
{   
    public $con = false;
    public $dbSelected = false;
    public $activeConnection = null;
    public $dataBaseName = "";
    function __contruct($dbUserName, $dbPassword, $server = "localhost")
    {
        $this->con = mysql_connect($server,$dbUserName,$dbPassword);
        if(!$this->con)
        {
            $this->activeConnection = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->activeConnection = true;
        }
    }
    // Says the error is on the line bellow
    public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = $this->con)
    {
        $this->dbSelected = mysql_select_db($dbName, $identifyer);
        $this->dataBaseName = $dbName;
        if($this->dbSelected != true)
        {
            $this->connectionErrorReport();
        }
    }
    //... Class continues on but is unimportant.
```

I get an Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in [path] on line 21

I have stared at it so long I really could use some help.

Comment: What version of PHP do you have where you are running this?

Comment: It may have to do with the `$this->con` but I am not 100% on that

Comment: [From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php): _The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's not a valid syntax. do this:

```
public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = null)
{
    if ($identifyer === null)
      $identifyer = this->con;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the short consise answer that was the problem and to all of you that said basically the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = $this->con) { ... }
```

Should be something like this:

```
public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = null)
{
    $identifyer = $identifyer ? $identifyer : $this->con;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = $this->con)
```

You can't use a variable as a default parameter.  You need to set `$identifyer` to a value.

You can do something like this:

```
public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = FALSE){
    $identifyer = $identifyer === FALSE ? $this->con : $identifyer;
    // rest of function
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you assign a default value to a function parameter it must be a constant, it cannot be a runtime-assigned value.

e.g.:

```
public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = 12345) //this is okay

public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = $something) //this is not okay
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not say this: $identifyer = $this->con

Try to set the default value to NULL and check it in the method.

Answer (score 0):

$this->con is the problem, but as its a public function you can access $this->con.

```
 public function dbConnect($dbName )
 {
    $identifyer = $this->con;
    $this->dbSelected = mysql_select_db($dbName, $identifyer);
    $this->dataBaseName = $dbName;
    if($this->dbSelected != true)
    {
        $this->connectionErrorReport();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of

```
$identifyer = $this->con)
```

The php documentation states that for default argument values... `The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.`

Answer (score -1):

Replace `public $identifyer = $this->con` with simply `$identifyer`.

You can only pass **static** variables as an argument's default value like this: `public function test($value = self::default_value)`.

This should work:

```
public function dbConnect($dbName, $identifyer = NULL)
{
    NULL === $identifyer AND $identifyer = $this->con;
    $this->dbSelected = mysql_select_db($dbName, $identifyer);
    $this->dataBaseName = $dbName;
    if($this->dbSelected != true)
    {
        $this->connectionErrorReport();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for "For god's sake".  Don't be rude.

Comment: The value **must** be a constant, so you can only use static variables if they are in fact constants.

Comment: Forgot to mention... agree and thanks for correcting.